# DHTMLX Scheduler Month View only event count

Tags: dhtml, dhtmlx-scheduler

[image]1) In month view events are visible, instead of those events I want to show the counts only. How this can be achieved in DHTMLX Scheduler JS version.

2) Enable date area click event in month view, not the event_link which directs to day or week view. Just need an event when In month view a date box is clicked I have to load events of that day only on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It can be implemented using `scheduler.addMarkedTimespan()` method. You need to iterate all days during the month, count events for each day by `scheduler.getEvents()` and then specify the result in the `html` parameter of `addMarkedTimespan`.

   ```
   function addEvCount(){
       var startDate = scheduler.getState().min_date;
       var endMonthDate = scheduler.getState().max_date;
       while(startDate.getTime() < endMonthDate.getTime()){
           var endDayDate = scheduler.date.add(startDate, 1, 'day');
           var evs = scheduler.getEvents(startDate, endDayDate);
           if(evs.length){
               scheduler.addMarkedTimespan({
                   start_date: startDate,
                   end_date: endDayDate,
                   html:"<div style='text-align:center;'><b>"+evs.length+"</b></div>",
                   css: "color"
               });
           }
           startDate = endDayDate;
       }
       scheduler.updateView();
   }
   ```

Please check how it works in the [snippet](https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/99e8e98cf).

To hide all events, use also Filtering Events.

```
 scheduler.filter_month = function(id, event){
       return false; // event will not be rendered
 }
```

The [updated demo](http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/05cc7d5dc) only with numbers and without rendered events.

Related docs: [addMarkedTimespan()](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_addmarkedtimespan.html), [getEvents()](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_getevents.html), [Filtering](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/filtering.html).

2. There is [onEmptyClick](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_onemptyclick_event.html) event which fires when the user clicks on an empty space in the scheduler (not on events). [Demo](http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/5/679c950ce).